# Forcing a view in clearcase to equal parent stream

Tags: clearcase

I have a clearcase view which I have not updated in quite some time. It has some view private files and I am sure a lot of other things as well. Is there anyway I can delete all the content of the view and force clearcase to give me everything again?

When i try to build the project from my view (After a rebase) I get a lot of build errors, but if I build the project from the actual stream, I get no build errors at all, so I am guessing my view is a bit messed up, and as I have no files I need to keep there, i would very much like to just reset it.

EDIT:
I am using a snapshot view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure that that your config spec reflect the config of your UCM Stream.

If we are talking about a snapshot view, simply delete everything in it (except the hidden `view.dat` file), and type (at the root directory of your snapshot view):

```
cleartool setcs -stream
```

That will force the view to:

- rewrite its config spec in accordance with its associated Stream
- launch an update of your snapshot view.

Comment: I renamed the folder containing the view and created a new directory with the same name. I then run setcs -tag "my view name" -default. The error I get is "Unable to get snapshot view handle : not a clearcase object"

Comment: Ok, apparently I am not as clever is I would like. Got the command to work now. I was trying to run the command from cleartool.exe. Running the tool from inside clearcase fixed it. Waiting for it to finish now

Comment: @user1038502: just type all your `cleartool` commands from the DOS session. Much safer that way. No need to type `cleartool`, and then type commands within a `cleartool` session.