# Update all entire clearcase view after rebasing 

Tags: version-control, version, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

When a rebase is carried out, all checkouts on the child stream are prevented.

Indeed, Clearcase has to ensure that all entire view is based on the new stream configuration and thus displays this message:

> The stream's configuration has changed. This update operation will
>   make the view show the new configuration. Do you want to update the
>   view now?

I try to imagine a scenario which would explain the absolute necessity of updating ALL the view.

I imagine the case where a rebase was made from an older foundation baseline.
So, the current child's configuration stream being still based on current parent's baseline, the keep of files would involve uncohesive state if no update was executed within it.

What are the good reasons to execute this full update ?

Suppose there wasn't that prevention:

What was the potential issue if, after a rebase, I was able to modify a file within stream's child and checkined it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only an update of all the view will include the rewrite of the config spec.

If you don't update the full view and checkin a file, you would do so based on the previous baseline for that file, as opposed to the new baseline specified during the rebase.

See also "[Forcing a view in clearcase to equal parent stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428274/forcing-a-view-in-clearcase-to-equal-parent-stream/9428378#9428378)" for the cleartool command behind that operation.

Comment: Thanks :) I suppose there are many other reasons than potential issues of baseline, don't I?

Comment: @Mik378 Well that is the main reason: coherency with the stream configuration. Plus, during the update, the files already in checked-out are preserved.