# Forcing a view in clearcase to equal parent stream -- dynamic

Tags: clearcase

I've seen [Forcing a view in clearcase to equal parent stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428274/forcing-a-view-in-clearcase-to-equal-parent-stream)

However I've got a dynamic stream, and I've got to the point of rebasing etc but there are still changes from files that have not been removed on the parent stream.

Question in clarity: How do you reset a dynamic view to exactly its parent? (and to save time so far I've generated a new stream and view, but I can't keep doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

A stream is not "dynamic". A view (UCM or not) can be a dynamic view.

A simpler approach would be:

- put baselines on the parent stream, to mark the current codebase state for each UCM component
- to rebase the integration stream with the same *latest* baselines as the one you just created on the parent
- do so with a new dynamic view (to make sure it reflects the stream, without any checked out or private file)

That way, the child stream would see the current LATEST of the parent stream.